# PDFLaTex complier gives a lot of errors after using LaTex compiler on Texmaker

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmaker, compilation-error

I use texmaker program to produce latex documents in my macbook. 
I have used PDFLaTex compiler to generate pdf documents, and it works perfectly.

For once, I mistakenly choose Latex compiler instead of PDFLaTex, and program gave errors. Afterwards all my trials with use of PDFLaTex compiler gave a lot of errors. Basically it gives error for everything.

I deleted all auxillary files for the chapters, but still PDFLatex gives a lot of errors.

Now I cannot produce the document, I was producing before. Is there any idea what went wrong ?

*** One weird fact that I have discovered. I have changed

```
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
```

block, now it doesn't give error. But, I have lots of remaining errors.

Best Regards
[image: errors after using PDFLatex Compiler]

Comment: Cristal balls are in short supply when all you give us is the 1385 error instead of the first one did you check you can pdfLaTeX a small simple file did you delete all the auxiliary files for the big.tex and all its chapters that were working did you try to save them in afresh plain name folder so they have no history of a latex run

Comment: I deleted all aux files in chapters. Then, i run again. It still gives errors.

Comment: Mention that in the question and add a simple small file that fails with the .log file it produces

Comment: the screenshot gives almost no information to allow anyone to help you, they are not the error messages, just a summary shown by your editor that omits most of the information. Also most errors after the first are likely to be spurious. Show the first error message from the log file as a code block so line ends are preserved, all the  lines from `!` to `?`

Comment: Is there any news here?